# Is this a bug in the Array.fill method in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Should this be the case i.e. I am misunderstanding, or is it a bug?

```
a = Array.new(3, Array.new(3))
a[1].fill('g')

=> [["g", "g", "g"], ["g", "g", "g"], ["g", "g", "g"]]
```

should it not result in:

```
=> [[nil, nil, nil], ["g", "g", "g"], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Array.new(3, Array.new(3))` returns an array which contains the same array three times (in other words: the expression `Array.new(3)` is evaluated exactly once and no copies are made).

What you probably want is `Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }`, which evaluates `Array.new(3)` three times and thus gives you an array of three independent arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, `Array.new(array)`  returns a new array created with size copies of obj (that is, size references to the same obj)